# Pass a group of bash commands to bash function

Tags: bash, pipe, command, group, bash-functions

I want to pass the following group of bash commands

```bsh
{ echo Apple; echo Banana; }
```

as an argument to a bash function defined in `.bashrc` as follows:

```bsh
BashFunction(){
"$@" | SomeOtherFunction
}
```

```bsh
BashFunction '{ echo Apple; echo Banana; }'
```

But I get this error:

```bsh
{ echo Apple; echo Banana; }: command not found
```

---

If I remove the quotes from the bash function

```bsh
BashFunction(){
$@ | SomeOtherFunction
}
```

Then I get this error

```
{: command not found
```

Comment: See `eval`, but note that you're entering the danger zone.

Comment: @choroba As you mentioned about the danger, are there no safer way?

Comment: Why do you need to pass commands to a function?

Comment: I am using ansi2html to  save coloured terminal output as html. As it creates separate file for every command, I though of doing it for a group of relevant commands. Although what you said did work. But what are the dangers and can we make it safer?

Comment: The danger is you can run uncontrolled commands if the input is coming from a user. Also, quoting will drive you mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an array?

```
#! /bin/bash
myeval () {
    for command in "$@" ; do
        $command
    done | other_func
}

myeval 'echo Apple' 'echo Banana'
```